# Remediation for security vulnerability due to storing sensitive information in strings

Tags: java, strings, security

Security assessment of our codebase reported the following vulnerability -

> **Vulnerability Description**
>
> The method x() in xyz.java stores sensitive data in a String object,
>   making it impossible to reliably purge the data from memory.
>
> **Vulnerability Risk**
>
> Sensitive data (such as passwords, social security numbers, credit
>   card numbers etc) stored in memory can be leaked if memory is not
>   cleared after use. Often, Strings are used store sensitive data,
>   however, since String objects are immutable, removing the value of a
>   String from memory can only be done by the JVM garbage collector. The
>   garbage collector is not required to run unless the JVM is low on
>   memory, so there is no guarantee as to when garbage collection will
>   take place. In the event of an application crash, a memory dump of the
>   application might reveal sensitive data.

Sample code, with comment against line on which vulnerability has been reported -

```
String expDetails = "";
        // extract expiry year in YYYY
        if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(paymentDetails.getExpiryYear())) {
            expDetails = paymentDetails.getExpiryYear();
        }
        // expiry month in MM
        String monthStr = "";
        if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(paymentDetails.getExpiryMonth())) {
            int month = Integer.parseInt(paymentDetails.getExpiryMonth()) + 1;
            expDetails += month > 9 ? String.valueOf(month) : "0" + month; //Vulnerability reported in this line - String.valueOf() operation it seems.
        }

        try {
            reqParams.put("CardNum",
                    encrypt(params[4], paymentDetails.getCardNumber()));
            reqParams.put("expiryDate", encrypt(params[4], expDetails));
            reqParams.put("CVVNum",
                    encrypt(params[4], paymentDetails.getCvvNumber()));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

> **Remediation**
>
> Always be sure to clear sensitive data when it is no longer needed.
>   Instead of storing sensitive data in immutable objects like Strings,
>   use byte arrays or character arrays that can be programmatically
>   cleared.

If I alter this code to following, using a byte array, instead of a string -

```
    byte[] expDetailsNew = null;
    // extract expiry year in YYYY
    if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(paymentDetails.getExpiryYear())) {
        expDetailsNew = paymentDetails.getExpiryYear().getBytes();
    }
    // expiry month in MM
    String monthStr = "";
    if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(paymentDetails.getExpiryMonth())) {
        int month = Integer.parseInt(paymentDetails.getExpiryMonth()) + 1;
        if(month>9)
        {
            byte[] combined = new byte[expDetailsNew.length + Integer.toString(month).length()];
            System.arraycopy(expDetailsNew, 0, combined, 0, expDetailsNew.length);
            System.arraycopy(Integer.toString(month).getBytes(), 0, combined, expDetailsNew.length, Integer.toString(month).length());
            expDetailsNew = combined;
        }
    }

    try {
        reqParams.put("CardNum",
                encrypt(params[4], paymentDetails.getCardNumber()));
        reqParams.put("expiryDate", encrypt(params[4], new String(expDetailsNew))); //I still need to do new String() here
        expDetailsNew = null;
        reqParams.put("CVVNum",
                encrypt(params[4], paymentDetails.getCvvNumber()));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

I still need to do new String() at one point, as commented above. Does the vulnerability still remain?

**Update**

The same vulnerability has also been reported in the following segment as well -

```
String decValue = null;

        if(someCondition)
        {
            decValue = CitruspgEncryptionUtil.decrypt(encText, key); //Not reported here
        }
        .. many else if blocks which assign string value to decValue variable, but not reported on these
       .. 
else if(someOtherCondition)
        {

            decValue = String.valueOf(someMethodReturningStringOutput); //Vulnerability reported due to the String.valueOf() it seems.
        }
```

It is not clear how the last case only is vulnerable. Also, what would be the fix here.

**Update 2**

Method encrypt being called from try block of 1st example -

```
private String encrypt(String pKey, String pData) throws Exception {

        byte[] lKey = Hex.fromString(pKey);
        byte[] lData = Hex.fromString(pData);

        //lKey, lData are then used as such..
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Is this code in a web application? Where do the parameters come from?

Comment: Seems a bit pointless - there already are Strings with card details in `paymentDetails `object, it is impossible to clear them. Also that rule makes more sense in case of encryption keys - and it looks like `params[4]` is also a String instead of char[]/byte[]

Answer (score 1):

I'll attempt to make two points:

1. Differentiate where Strings are held in a pool; and,
2. Evaluate the code-duration where the sting value is held (i.e. start-to-finish number lines of code).

Since Java 11 (if I recall correctly), all strings not using Unicode are byte arrays.  So the discussion should be about whether the reference to a string is shared (within a pool) and how long the memory of its contents exist.

Code that creates a string without thy key word 'new' (e.g. `String monthStr = "";`) will create the string reference in a pool shared within the JVM.  I do not recommend sensitive data in a shared pool of strings.

Since you are performing string manipulation, I recommend the StringBuilder class.  This class uses a character array.  You should be able to avoid false-positive code scans with this class.  As soon as you are done with the contents of the StringBuilder class you should clear its memory with either: `expDetails.replace(0, expDetails.length(), "*");` or `expDetails.delete(0, expDetails.length());`  If you continue with your byte array solution I recommend implementing code that writes over the array data after you call the `.put(...) method`.